# in Databricks, how to create a SQL function with dynamic variables in a notebook

Tags: python, sql-server, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I would like to migrate SQL tables, procedures and functions to databrick's notebook. How can I create functions and procedures with parameters?

This is a new architecture, I used to save data from the Azure data lake to Azure database.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION [db_name].table (@par1 int, @par2 varchar(10)) returns varchar(10) as
begin
      declare @var1  varchar(10);
      declare @var2 int;     
...
ends;
```

I get this error

> Error in SQL statement: ParseException: mismatched input 'begin'
>   expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'DESC', 'WITH', 'VALUES',
>   'CREATE', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 'SHOW',
>   'USE', 'DROP', 'ALTER', 'MAP', 'SET', 'RESET', 'START', 'COMMIT',
>   'ROLLBACK', 'MERGE', 'UPDATE', 'CONVERT', 'REDUCE', 'REFRESH',
>   'CLEAR', 'CACHE', 'UNCACHE', 'DFS', 'TRUNCATE', 'ANALYZE', 'LIST',
>   'REVOKE', 'GRANT', 'LOCK', 'UNLOCK', 'MSCK', 'EXPORT', 'IMPORT',
>   'LOAD', 'OPTIMIZE'}(line 1, pos 0)
>
> == SQL == declare @var1 ^^^   return 0